# no match for 'operator==' (operand types are QSerialPortInfo and const QSerialPortInfo)

Tags: qt, qtserialport

The following code is part of subclass of `QThread` in which I am trying to discover any newly connected Serial Ports.

```
void PortEnumerationThread::run ()
{
  QList<QSerialPortInfo> port_list, discovered_ports;

  discovered_ports = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();


  int i;

  while (1)
  {
    port_list = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

    for (i=0;i<port_list.size();i++)
    {
        if (!discovered_ports.contains(port_list.at(i)))
            emit new_port_found (port_list.at(i).portName());
    }
    discovered_ports = port_list;
    sleep ( SLEEP_TIME );
  }

}
```

Above code is throwing following compilation error at line 
 `if (!discovered_ports.contains(port_list.at(i)))`:

> QtCore/qlist.h: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are
>   QSerialPortInfo and const QSerialPortInfo)

Comment: `QList::contains()` function's description says: "This function requires the value type to have an implementation of operator==().", which `QSerialPortInfo` doesn't have.

Comment: Ok, So, Will I have to loop through the QList or is there any other way except contains() function to find a matching QSerialPortInfo in the list  ??

Comment: I'd go with std::find_if and a custom functor for the equality check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to you could always implement your own version of `operator==` for `QSerialPortInfo`.  You'd need to make certain it didn't have other undesirable side effects elsewhere in your code though.

Something like...

```
#include <tuple>
#include <QList>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>

bool operator== (const QSerialPortInfo &a, const QSerialPortInfo &b)
{
  return
    std::forward_as_tuple(a.description(),
                          a.manufacturer(),
                          a.portName(),
                          a.productIdentifier(),
                          a.serialNumber())
    ==
    std::forward_as_tuple(b.description(),
                          b.manufacturer(),
                          b.portName(),
                          b.productIdentifier(),
                          b.serialNumber());
}
```

You'd probably want to check the subset of properties you consider to be of importance for equality -- I just had a rough guess.